# Is it possible to get both Live Trigger rewards in a single play-through?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

In *Final Fantasy XIII-2*, there are "Live Trigger" events where you can select amongst a number of dialog options. Depending on what you do in an area, you get a "good" (non-potion) reward for doing one of two things:

1. Activating a number (usually most or all) of the live triggers
2. Activating the same number of live triggers in (1), but choosing the "funny" option for some subset of them

The strategy guide mentions you can go back to most areas to get the live triggers you missed, but it's not clear whether that means just the ones you didn't activate the first time, or if it means you can redo the live triggers and get both rewards: the "serious" reward and the "funny" reward.

Is it possible to get both sets of rewards in a single play-through, or does it take multiple play-throughs?

Comment: I would imagine this ties into the New Game+ feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Yuck mentions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/49360/3389) in his answer on whether a new game plus mode exists, each area has an item that—once retrieved—lets you reset the area and play through the events again. This allows you to pick different Live Trigger options and get the reward you missed.

As an example, once you complete *New Bodhum -003 AF-*, the next stop is *Bresha Ruins -005 AF-*. There, you'll find a key item called the *'Leaving' Gate Seal*, which allows you to close the *New Bodhum -003 AF-* gate. [Closing a gate will reset the events of the area](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/49441/3389), and thus, allow you to get the reward.

Also of note is that closing a gate will unlock new Live Trigger choices, replacing some of the old ones. Based on the list in the strategy guide, most of the replacement choices are the "funny" options, so an efficient strategy would be to get the "serious" reward first, then get the "funny" reward once you can close the gate seal for the area.

Answer (score -2):

If you get a potion you can replay to get one of the true rewards, but if you get one of them you can't get the other one in the same playthrough.