# Does Final Fantasy XIII-2 have a "new game plus" mode?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

It's seems pretty clear, between the [Live Trigger system](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/49196/3389) (where you can generally only choose one dialogue option), other mutually-exclusive choices, and the talk of [monthly DLC](http://www.rpgamer.com/news/Q4-2011/101211a.html) that Square-Enix expects people to play through *Final Fantasy XIII-2* multiple times.

But it's not clear, at least to me, whether there's a new game plus option, where you can keep some or all of your original progress as you restart the game: an interview (in Japanese) back in December 2011 [supposedly mentioned the mode](http://www.joystiq.com/2011/12/07/ffxiii-2-will-have-new-game-plus-mode-offers-bonuses-for-ffxi/), but neither the manual nor the official strategy guide mention it, and I can't find a confirmation from anyone who actually played the game that the mode was ever implemented.

Is it available, or is it impossible to get 100% completion in any individual play-through due to various decision trees locking certain options out?

Comment: You mean the game has been out for 24 hours and you haven't beaten it yet?! ;-)

Comment: @bwarner I need at *least* two days to do that :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's kind of irrelevant as you can bounce around between each time period and zone whenever you'd like. From [New Game+ for FF XIII-2](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/619315-final-fantasy-xiii-2/61722756):

> There isn't really a new game+.
>
> You're just able to reverse time so you can replay any section of the
>   story or area once you find a reverse clock item [seal] in the corresponding
>   time period.

Comment: Hm, I've gained access to the Historia Crux, but there doesn't seem to be a way to replay areas (like a New Game+ mode would imply): if For example, if I go back to *New Bodhum -003 AF-*, it's stuck at the end of the events that happened there. Is there a replay option that unlocks later on?

Comment: @MarkTrapp If there's any content that can be experienced differently, you can press `R1` (for PS3) to *lock* the portal and start it fresh. Some don't have that option because as far as I can tell there's no story-changing events. This is how you get the `Anomalous` trophy / achievement.

Comment: I just found the item that lets you reset *New Bodhum -003 AF-*: the *'Leaving' Gate Seal*. Really weird mechanic.