# Does it matter what I say?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

In FFXIII-2 they added user input to conversation. Does any of this have lasting input on the game? I noticed that some places it'll reject my choice and make me pick again, but most times it seems that I can say whatever I want.

Does any of this affect the gameplay or is it just to get different reactions in that conversation?

Comment: [But Thou Must!](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ButThouMust)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it does affect a few things.

First, if you make a clearly goofy selection you'll get a Live Trigger Reward *other* than a potion. Why this is doesn't make any sense to me, but picking the *right* or logical answer won't net you anything. The rewards here are almost always cosmetic so you're not missing much of anything.

Second, some of the live triggers will result in a Paradox Ending. These are, simply put, **bad endings** to the game. When you come into a Paradox Ending there will be a short scene and you'll be dumped back to the Historia Crux.

The unique thing about FF 13-2 is that all of these choices can be replayed by closing and opening gates again. Everything in the zone gets reset other than key items and fragments. So if you're not satisfied with how your first choices turn out you can simply go through it again.

Comment: There are [two live trigger rewards for each "group" of live triggers](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/49196/3389): if you manage to find all the live triggers in the group, you get one reward. If you find them all and choose a certain number of funny options, you get a different reward. You only get a potion if you manage to miss a live trigger in the group.

Comment: -1 they aren't bad endings. I can remember at least two which end better than the actual in game ending